# Error creating bean with name org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration (Using Gradle)

Tags: gradle, intellij-idea, jar, executable-jar, intellij-14

Building jar file works through the terminal `computer path % ./gradlew build`, and application runs `computer path % java -jar name.jar`.
Why not through IntelliJ?

*Secondary Issue -
When I try to upload the jar file built through the terminal to AWS Beanstalk I get a validation error.

*Primary Issue -
The application runs in IntelliJ.
After I have completed the Project Structure setup, and the Build Artifacts execution. The new .jar file fails to run,
throwing the exception below.

```
Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaConfiguration': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceConfiguration$Hikari.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource]: Factory method 'dataSource' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties$DataSourceBeanCreationException: Failed to determine a suitable driver class
```

build.gradle:

```
    plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.6.2'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'application'

}

group = 'com.example'
version = 'api'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'

    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

mainClassName = 'com.example.name.applicationame'

task fatJar(type: Jar) {
    bootJar {
        launchScript()
    }
    manifest {
        attributes 'Main-Class': "${mainClassName}"
        duplicatesStrategy = 'include'
    }
    archiveBaseName = "name"
    from { configurations.compileClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) } }
    with jar
}
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/name?useSSL=true
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Thanks!

Comment: Seems to be classpath-related. I'd submit a bug request with a sample project to YouTrack. Here is the example: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-280954

Comment: I will check this out, thanks!